# Telegram Bot only reply message to sender (in group chat)

Tags: java, spring-boot, telegram-bot

I am working on a telegram bot project, I would like to know if it is possible for bot to reply back to same user that sends the command in group chat, but not have the rest of the group see it?

Can I do that? If so, what is the direction?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: As far as I know (last time used the API is over a year ago) that is not possible by design. A bot may only answer a user who started a conversation first. Otherwise you would be spammed by bots. You could implement something where the user has to explicitly contact your bot to enable direct replies.